# Testing with Linked ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am rather new to ARM Templates in Azure and I need to deploy a resource group that has about 40 resources in it. I keep getting lost in all of the json, and it looks like splitting the template into linked templates would help.

I found suggestions for creating a storage account where the templates could be uploaded and run. I set up a build and release in VSTS to do this. The problem is, now that I did my first test, I'm not sure how to do it again. I haven't found a way to automatically remove the templates, or even the container, from the first test from the storage account. I would rather keep the storage account and use it over and over for deployment.

I also saw a suggestion for using a virtual machine instead of a storage account, but I feel I know so little about how to do that where it would just be more effective to have the one big ARM template.

If anyone can help me with deleting files from a storage account through the VSTS build and release, I would greatly appreciate it. I also welcome other suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the templates from your storage account? Presumably, you use the templates as part of your deployment or CI process so that you can guarantee that your infrastructure and services are always configured as you expect.

Comment: The templates are already in the VSTS version control, so I don't see a reason to keep them in the storage account. I suppose I could keep changing the template name for each deployment test. That would mean checking in a new template into source control for each test and I would lose the built-in change tracking.

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to have addressable URLs for each sub-template so that you can embed them. You also need to update the templates in storage before each deploy so that you can incorporate changes. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. And many times I don't make changes to the templates, it is the build or release task list that gets changed. This is all testing to get the deployment working properly so I know what will happen when I deploy to a production environment. I suppose I'm basically trying to automatically reset my test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Azure File Copy task in VSTS to copy your sub-templates to a blob container. Then you can execute your ARM task.

[Azure File Copy Task description](http://%20https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopy/README.md)

Comment: I was not able to use the link above, but I do have this [Deploy: Azure File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy) I was using that to copy the files to the storage account. The docs don't say what happens if the files are already there. I thought I tried it and it failed, but just now I tried it and for both blob storage and general storage accounts the files were simply overwritten. That works for me! Thanks for your help!